# what does the -i flag mean in expect?

Tags: tcl, expect

I see some code `exp_send -i $bash_id "/bin/tcsh"`, what does the  `-i flag` means? what is the meaning of -i flag after the `exp_send`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expect allows you to spawn multiple processes at once and then interact with them in a mixed way. This is a very powerful mechanism, but it does mean that when you are saying what to `exp_send` to or `expect` from, you have to say what you are talking about. That is done by using the `-i` flag to specify the *spawn id*, which is returned by `spawn` when a subprocess is created.

When there's only a single subprocess, the `-i` can be omitted as the global `spawn_id` variable is used by default.